# Use top level await in CJS script and import a ES module

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-modules, commonjs

I was fixing a vulnerable jar for my CJS service which was earlier being used by `require` keyword:

```
helper.js:
----------
const foo = require('formidable');
function saveFile(req, location) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
   // use foo...
 }
}

index.js:
---------
helper = require('./helper')
// use helper...
```

The latest version of formidable is in ES so `require` does not work. I tried searching and found that dynamic import might solve this.

1. Brute force approach didn't work. Compilation was success but while running it said `constructor not found` while instantiating formidable.

```
helper.js:
----------
const  foo = import('formidable');
function saveFile(req, location) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
   // use foo...
 }
}
```

2. Added **await** to first line `const  foo = await import('formidable');` Doesnt work get an error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`
3. Tried making saveFile function async too but doesn't work. same error as in 2.

Now I cant covert my whole service to module by adding type=module in package.json as that will impact 100s of files. Is there any other approach to just import the new ES module **formidable** and use it without changing existing behavior too much ?

P.S: Using Node 16.1. Pls let me know if more info is needed. Happy to mark duplicate if similar exists.

Comment: The ES equivalent of -> `const foo = require('formidable');` would be `import * as foo from "formidable";`

Comment: @Keith if i do that it is forcing me to convert my whole project to ES module by doing type=module which like i said is impacting hundreds files. I can try once more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should write new code in ES modules.  They seem to just be the better of options nowadays.

Anyway, you can use `.then()`:

```js
const fooPromise = import('formidable');

function saveFile(req, location){
    return new Promise((rslv, rjct) => {
        fooPromise.then(foo => {
            // Do stuff with foo.
        });
    };
}
```

#### Update

Now that I think of it, you can actually make `saveFile()` async and await the `fooPromise`:

```js
async function saveFile(req, location) {
    const foo = await fooPromise;
    // Do stuff with foo.
}
```

Comment: Why in the world would you wrap a manually created promise around another existing promise?  That's considered an **anti-pattern**.  You can just `return fooPromise.then(...)` instead.

Comment: I am technically not doing it.  I just adapted the code the user has.  I am merely showing a sample on how to obtain actual `foo`.

Comment: Well, you're the one that first showed the anti-pattern as that was not in the OP's question.  That is never needed.

Comment: Using .then makes my parent api call itself asynchronous. Anyway to achieve synchronous behavior in the parent api ?

Comment: using async - await worked. Not sure why .then was not working, theoretically it should have. Also I found there is no way to make all the parent api /codeflow synchronous unless they are put in .then() clause after calling async function

Comment: @pxm sounds like you are not coding in ES modules.  If you are using `require()` you're doing CommonJS modules.  CommonJS does not, and will never support top-level awaits.  I recommend writing code in ES modules going forward.